# For Python, why does Selenium not read Geckodriver yet read Chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, path, geckodriver

So basically, I added geckodriver.exe to the environment variables Path on Windows 10, yet trying

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
```

still resulted in the error message that "Geckodriver" executables need to be installed on Path

Now, I installed Chrome and the chromedriver.exe file off the web and ran chromedriver on Selenium just fine

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Chrome(r'c:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
```

This works and Google Chrome is open, so now I try to add the path in Firefox and when the path suggestions are showing up, selenium doesn't even recognize the geckodriver.exe exists, and pathlib does recognize the Path('c:/geckodriver/geckodriver.exe').exists()==True.

```
browser=webdriver.Firefox(r'c:\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe')

NotADirectoryError
```

So selenium is saying that the .exe file that clearly exists does not exist. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For FireFox webdriver you'll need to set the path like this:

```
browser=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'c:\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe')
```